# Facebook share image is always small, no large thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I am using this code to show post with image on facebook:

```
                // Open FB share popup
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'share_open_graph',
                    action_type: 'og.shares',
                    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                        object: {
                            'og:url': FBLink,
                            'og:title': '',
                            'og:description': '',
                            'og:image:width' : '1200',
                            'og:image:height' :'630',
                            'og:image': FBPic
                        }
                    })
                },
                function (response) {
                // Action after response
                })
```

And the image is always small on the left, and text on the right, like no full width thumbnail preview, even tho the image is full size.

I tried scaping it with debugger, it gets its size fine in there, 1200x630, still no luck

I tried adding og:type 'article', but then just get this error: 'conflicting og:type found in path (object) and 'properties' (article)';

I am running out of ideas. Image is just small no matter what I do. Any advices?

Comment: Is your app in the Games category? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Hmm that is true, it was in games category. I changed it, but still, same result so far,

Comment: Might generally be the case for this kind of share. My guess is, they are probably going to remove this way to still overwrite these parameters at runtime soon anyway, because it seems after the disabled that for normal shares, everyone is switching to (fake) Open Graph stories now to still get the same functionality.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Probably the best to go then it to create real landing page for every image

Comment: Well, same results with normal html too, I guess the problem is not with my code then

Comment: Have you switched to a "normal" link share, or are you still using `share_open_graph`?

Comment: I switched to 'normal' when using simle html page with og tags

Comment: when I share using link provided at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/  it shows fine, full-width. HMMMM

Comment: NAILED IT! "If you are using the Facebook SDK for JavaScript, this will default to a modal iframe type for people logged into your app" - because I am logged in into app being its admin, I always get iframe, and iframe never shows full width. CBroe, thanks for being here, your inputs really helped me to go forward